# return v.compareTo(w) < 0; what influence does the "< 0" serve?

Tags: java

the source of the line is provided below, i understand what v.compareTo(w) does but i am curious as to what influence the "< 0" has, does it not allow it to return if compareTo returns 1 which is greater than 0? does it not return if anything if compareTo returns 0 because it is equal to 0?

```
private static boolean less(Comparable v, Comparable w)   
{  
    return v.compareTo(w) < 0; 
}
```

Comment: *"i understand what v.compareTo(w) does"* ... are you sure about that? You might want to re-check that `compareTo` returns, then you understand what `< 0` does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `compareTo()` method returns an integer value. Either 0, 1, or -1. Using to values (`a` and `b`)as an example:

```
a.compareTo(b);
```

- `a >  b`,  you get `1`
- `a == b`, you get `0`
- `a <  b`,  you get `-1`

---

> what influence does the “< 0” serve?

From your given method implementation:

```
return v.compareTo(w) < 0;
       |------------|
             V
    return 0 or 1 or -1

// return  0 if v == w
// return  1 if v >  w
// return -1 if v <  w
```

Since the only scenario for `v.compareTo(w)` to be lesser than 0 is when `v < w`, it is equivalent as saying:

return **TRUE** if (v < w), else return **FALSE**

Comment: *"Either 0, 1, or -1"* This is not quite true. The returned value doesn't need to be that, it can be _any_ positive or negative number.

Comment: @Tom That is true. But I try to give a simple scenario whereby `a > b, you get 1` in the case of comparing Integers. Maybe I should have stated this is the case for Integers.

Answer (score 2):

The function is named `less`. It should only return `true` in the case where `v` is less than `w`. Otherwise it will return `false`.

Answer (score 0):

The compareTo() function returns an integer value. However, by adding a condition operator `<`, the statement `v.compareTo(w) < 0` returns a boolean. It translates to "if the value returned by compareTo is less than 0" aka "if v is less than w". If v is less than w, then that statement will evaluate to true and the method you have will return true. Otherwise, the statement will evaluate to false and the method will return false. I would advise printing out the value returned by your method because then it becomes clear that your method returns a boolean value.

Answer (score 0):

You need the `<` to convert the `int` result of `v.compareTo(w)` to a `boolean`. The other relational operators would also convert the two `int`s to a `boolean`, but `<` is the appropriate one for a method named "less".

---

Your code is not type-safe, because nothing constrains `v` and `w` to be mutually comparable, since they are raw-typed.

For instance, you could call this method with:

```
less(0, "")
```

which would yield a `ClassCastException`.

Instead, you should write this as:

```
private static <C extends Comparable<C>> boolean less(C v, C w) {
  return v.compareTo(w) < 0;
}
```